# Requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I was trying to install jasonlewis/enhanced-router package in laravel-starter-kit, and when I run composer update it doesn't install and gives some errors. Initially I thought the problem was from the composer line for the jasonlewis/enhanced-router (`"jasonlewis/enhanced-router": "dev-master"`) but I removed it and have the same error.

I tried to search for some similar problems, but can't figure out what is the dependency problem I'm getting.

Below is the result I get after running `composer update`:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework 4.0.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 4.0.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA4
    - Installation request for zizaco/confide dev-master -> satisfiable by zizaco/confide[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA3
    - bllim/datatables dev-master requires illuminate/filesystem >=4.0.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.0.x-dev,
4.1.x-dev, dev-master, 4.2.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.
9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9], illuminat
e/filesystem[4.0.x-dev, 4.1.x-dev, dev-master, 4.2.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.
6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4
.1.8, v4.1.9].
    - bllim/datatables 1.3.0 requires illuminate/filesystem >=4.0.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.0.x-dev, 4.1.x
-dev, dev-master, 4.2.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4
.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9], illuminate/fil
esystem[4.0.x-dev, 4.1.x-dev, dev-master, 4.2.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4
.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8,
 v4.1.9].
    - bllim/datatables dev-master requires illuminate/filesystem >=4.0.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.0.x-dev,
4.1.x-dev, dev-master, 4.2.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.
9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9], illuminat
e/filesystem[4.0.x-dev, 4.1.x-dev, dev-master, 4.2.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.
6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4
.1.8, v4.1.9].
    - bllim/datatables v1.3.1 requires illuminate/filesystem >=4.0.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.0.x-dev, 4.1.
x-dev, dev-master, 4.2.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v
4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9], illuminate/fi
lesystem[4.0.x-dev, 4.1.x-dev, dev-master, 4.2.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v
4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8
, v4.1.9].
    - bllim/datatables v1.3.2 requires illuminate/filesystem >=4.0.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.0.x-dev, 4.1.
x-dev, dev-master, 4.2.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v
4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9], illuminate/fi
lesystem[4.0.x-dev, 4.1.x-dev, dev-master, 4.2.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v
4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8
, v4.1.9].
    - bllim/datatables v1.3.3 requires illuminate/filesystem >=4.0.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.0.x-dev, 4.1.
x-dev, dev-master, 4.2.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v
4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9], illuminate/fi
lesystem[4.0.x-dev, 4.1.x-dev, dev-master, 4.2.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v
4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8
, v4.1.9].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.0.0-BETA2, 4.1.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.0.0-BETA2, dev-master].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.0.0-BETA2, 4.2.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.0, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.1, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.10, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.11, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.12, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.2, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.3, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.4, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.5, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.6, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.7, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.8, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v4.1.9, v4.0.0-BETA2].
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem 4.0.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v4.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v4.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v4.0.10|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v4.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v4.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v4.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v4.0.5|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v4.0.6|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v4.0.7|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v4.0.8|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v4.0.9|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem 4.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem 4.2.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v4.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v4.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v4.1.10|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v4.1.11|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v4.1.12|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v4.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v4.1.3|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v4.1.4|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v4.1.5|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v4.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v4.1.7|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v4.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
    - don't install illuminate/filesystem v4.1.9|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
        - don't install illuminate/filesystem dev-master|don't install laravel/framework v4.0.0-BETA2
        - Installation request for laravel/framework 4.0.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.0.x-dev, v4.0.0, v4.0.0-BET
    A2, v4.0.0-BETA3, v4.0.0-BETA4, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9].
        - Installation request for bllim/datatables * -> satisfiable by bllim/datatables[1.3.0, dev-master, v1.3.1, v1.3.2,
    v1.3.3].
```

And my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "andrew13/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site",
    "description": "Laravel 4 Starter Site",
    "keywords": ["laravel","Starter Site"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Andrew Elkins",
            "homepage": "http://www.andrewelkins.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
        "twbs/bootstrap":  "3.0.0",
        "zizaco/confide": "dev-master",
        "zizaco/entrust": "dev-master",
        "jasonlewis/basset": "dev-master",
        "robclancy/presenter": "1.2.*",
        "j20/php-uuid": "dev-master",
        "bllim/datatables": "*",
        "blueimp/jquery-file-upload": "dev-master",
        "jasonlewis/enhanced-router": "dev-master"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "way/generators": "dev-master",
        "mockery/mockery": "dev-master@dev",
        "summerstreet/woodling": "0.1.*",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "dev-master",
        "leafo/lessphp": "v0.4.0",
        "natxet/CssMin": "dev-master",
        "lmammino/jsmin4assetic": "1.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [

            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/library",
            "app/models",
            "app/presenters",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/library"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

I did not start from basic Laravel package, I've used `andrew13/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site`

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Welcome to the worst feature of Composer!

So the problem is that you have conflict in your dependencies that is hard to spot.

You have a requirement for `"laravel/framework": "4.0.*",` in your composer.json. You also have a requirement for `"zizaco/confide": "dev-master"`

Looking in the composer.json for 'zizaco/confide' in github we see:

> "illuminate/support": "4.1.x",

The Composer feature that's causing you a problem is that the `replace` keyword ***OPERATES GLOBALLY ACROSS THE WHOLE OF PACKAGIST***.

So because the ['illuminate/support' package is replace'd by Laravel itself](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/composer.json#L38-L66) when Composer tries to satisfy the requirement of "illuminate/support": "4.1.x" it actually tries to download laravel version 4.1.x instead.

That clashes with your requirement of laravel version 4.0.* and so the set of dependencies can't be resolved.

I think there may be no trivial solution to your problem.

I was going to suggest specifying an earlier version of zizaco/confide rather than dev-master, that is dependent on illuminate/support version 4.0.x rather than 4.1.x - however that would mean switching from zizaco/confide 3.x to 2.x which is probably not acceptable.

The only other option would be to change your requirement from laravel 4.0.x to 4.1.* - which may or may not be acceptable, based on how much work that would cause you.

Comment: He can fork it and change the composer can't he ?

Comment: He could, but for various reasons forking code just to make small changes is really annoying in Composer.

Comment: BTW, if anyone arrives here with requirements mismatches that go the _other_ way—the package you're trying to install requires a dependency that's _older_ than one already installed—you can simply manually `composer require` the older package. Then install whatever package you want, and its requirements will be satisfied. You do this by appending the older version to the require statement. E.g., `composer require symfony/event-dispatcher ~2.2`.

Comment: Thank you @TylerHayes! Your comment was really helpful!

Comment: I'm new to Composer and I'm hoping even a few years on I can get this cleared up: *Why* would it try to change your versioning requirements on its own and install Laravel 4.1.x? Is that a typo? I'm having the same problem and I'm starting to worry there is no solution.

Comment: can you add a conflict on laravel 4.1.x?